# How to create player of sequence images in qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt, media

everyone!
I'm beginner. I am trying to create a player for playing images in qt, but I cannot figure out how to implement image updates in the widget. I tried using *QPaintEvent*, but it only wraps around the image when the window is resized. I understand that I need to use *QTimer*. The main question is how to implement a **method for updating images**.

Comment: One simple approach is to set the image as a pixmap on a label. Track your position in the set of images, and connect the timeout signal to a helper that sets the next image.

Comment: I understand that I need to connect the slot that updates the image on a timer. But I can't figure out how to do the window update, the method itself. Thanks for answer)

Comment: Please edit your question with C++ definitions of "the window" and "the widget".

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so that we don't have to guess what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [image-viewer example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html). You basically want to call its function `loadFile()` regularly with different files.

To do that you can use a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Of course the signal `timeout()` has no parameters, so you can not directly connect it to `loadFile()`. Instead you would have to come up with a slot called something like `loadNextFile()`, that knows what the current file is, determines the next file based upon that and then calls `loadFile()`.

```
void ImageViewer::loadNextFile()
{
   QString nextFile = this->determineNextFile(this->currentFile);
   this->loadFile(nextFile);
   this->currentFile = nextFile;
}
```